# Why can't I get bootstrap popover to work?

Tags: javascript, html

I've isolated the problem by creating a file that only has the required bootstrap template, popover code, and the "popover dismiss" script at the bottom so that nobody has to read my entire webpage to see what I'm referring to.  The popover is supposed to create a little window with information in it when clicked.  The dismiss script is supposed to make it disappear upon clicking.  Instead, nothing happens when the button is clicked.  Could someone take a look at it? I have no clue what the issue could be, as I followed instructions exactly.  The bootstrap css and the required jQuery/plugin scripts are properly placed within the document. I'd appreciate anyone's insight on why my popover is not functioning correctly.

Thanks!!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>

 <body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
Popover on top
  </button>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

    $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
trigger: 'focus'
})
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery `$('.popover-dismiss')` is searching for elements with class `popover-dismiss` but you don't have any such element, that's why nothing is happening. Use something like `$('[data-toggle="popover"]')` instead.

**Note: I have put the popover on bottom because there is no space on top but you can easily change that.**

**Edit: It works now. Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/shivanshukantprasad/pen/MBLLLp)**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>

 <body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-dismiss" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
Popover on top
  </button>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
      trigger: 'focus'
    });
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the class to my example below. However, it is targeted correctly in my original webpage and still doesn't work. Could there be something else?

Comment: Try wrapping the jquery in a `$(document).ready` since if the code is executed before the element is created it will cause issues.

Comment: Thank you Shivanshu! I will try that and let you know how it goes. Sorry for the late reply!